# Function to look up a string of text and return the cell number it is in

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know this is possible because I have seen it done before but I cannot seem to remember the proper function.

I want to be able to write a formula that can look in a worksheet, be able to find a cell that contains a text string like 'Date' for this example and return the cell number that it is in so that I may use it for another part of the project.

So say I have a set of data and the A column is headed with Date (A1 would be the string 'Date' and then all cells below it would be dates) I want to tell the function to search for 'Date' in the sheet and have it return "A1"

Thank you!

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). That information is rarely needed. And using a cell address in "another part of the project" implies using the `INDIRECT` function, which is volatile and can impair your workbook performance. If you are more specific about what you plan to do with this information, a better solution could be recommended. One example of a better solution would be to use a **Table** structure; then refer to the column with a structured reference, eg: `TableName[Date]`. But other solutions are also possible, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the other possible column headers are in `B1:C1` you could use the following:

```
=ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Date",A1:C1,0),4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string you want to find is in the header, then Clif's answer should do it.

If the string you want to find may be everywhere (A1:E4 in my example) and there are no duplicates then use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CELL("address",INDEX($A$1:$E$4,SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$E$4=G3)*(ROW($A$1:$E$4)-ROW($A$1)+1)),SUMPRODUCT(--($A$1:$E$1=G3)*(COLUMN($A$1:$E$1)-COLUMN($A$1)+1)))), "$", "")
```

If there may be duplicates and you want to find all the occurrences, then put the formula as array (enter this formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter, not only enter):

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF($A$1:$E$4=G4, ADDRESS(ROW($A$1:$E$4), COLUMN($A$1:$E$4), 4), ""))
```

[image: Example]

Comment: IMHO, the SUBSTITUTE() function in the last formula is not needed - the third parameter of the [**ADDRESS() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89) is 4 and this is enough to never have to replace the $ sign with an empty string. So the formula can be written a little shorter.